# multiple UIViewControllers in one ViewController with scrolling the content

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift2, swift3

I have been already set some code for reading more viewControllers in one MainViewController with tableView. Each viewController represent one section and one row in the MainViewController and i'm setting the height for row for given viewController by getting the full content of what that viewController have inside. So my only problem is when i'm trying to use "willDisplay cell" and "didEndDisplaying cell" methods, things got messed up. Tried to insert two viewControllers with smaller heights and it's fine. When i try to insert more viewControllers with bigger heights, they got mixed up in the view. Tried to debug and the code behind present me normal work. Beside in the screen is mess. They overlaps the content from one to another section while scrolling the content from MainVeiwController. Can someone give me any other idea how to add viewControllers contents in one MainViewController without getting into mixed up situations from "willDisplay cell" and "didEndDisplaying cell" methods.

https://s22.postimg.org/i83t96fxt/Screen_Shot_2016_11_25_at_2_39_07_PM.png

Comment: If your approach to design the layout is by adding `ViewController` to `UITableViewCells`, then IMO you need to revisit the architecture of your project. This isn't a good approach.

Comment: then how if you add viewController with cells that could be clicked? As i said in my explanation this is content, not fixed static layout....